# Ubuntu along with Windows

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I want to install Ununtu 14 and currently I am running Windows Vista. If I install Ununtu along with Windows, will I lose my programs after the installation? Also, I would like to install Ubuntu in an external HDD, after creating the partition for Ubuntu, will I lose all my stuff?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly why the "Install Ubuntu alongside X" option in the installer exists: To allow you the usage both of your existing system OS *and* Ubuntu. So you won't lose anything if the installation goes right.

When you want to install Ubuntu on another disk, select "Something else" instead of "install alongside". You have to manually set up where to install Ubuntu.

No matter what you do, I strongly recommend you to **backup all your files** before partitioning. Even if you know what you're doing when installing Ubuntu, you can still lose data due to partition corruption while partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this link can help you:

[DualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

Also since you have mentioned that you'll install Ubuntu in an external disk, you will be prompted two options during the system start. You can opt which one you'd like to get start.

Answer (score 0):

During the installation, Ubuntu will ask you to make some choices.

Everything is done to facilitate the installation in "dualboot", to have Windows and Linux. 
All you need to know : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

If you want to try Ubuntu without problem, you can test with a live USB (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).